# Can I get pixel measurements using Adobe Illustrator CS3?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been handed a few Adobe Illustrator to turn into web pages and it seems like Adobe Illustrator CS3 doesn't do measurements in in pixels by default. Is there a way to take measurements in pixels in Adobe Illustrator CS3 or do I need to export them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator is a vector graphics program ... meaning that it works with mathematical descriptions of lines/shapes/text etc, rather than dots, so until you export to a raster/bitmap format, it's not locked into any particular pixel resolution.  In fact that's why they call vector graphics "resolution independent".

But if you decide up front you're going to export at, say, 100dpi, then you know that each inch (in your AI graphic) will export to 100 pixels.  1/100 inch = 1 pixel.

Comment: I understand that, but since it's happy to convert to web I figured maybe I could get it to just give me the same pixel measurements right in the application without me needing to convert it to a PNG and firing up photoshop or some such.

Comment: It can't give you pixel measurements until you tell it how many pixels you'll export to when you make your PNG.  You could decide up front that you'll export at 72dpi, then set your unit of measure to points instead of inches.  72 points per inch, 72 dots per inch, so 1 point = one dot/pixel